# trying to set a TSFE variable in HMENU

Tags: typo3, typoscript

i'm trying to create a menubar with typoscript when im assigning an integer like `116` everything is working as expected but the thing is i dont know the page id and im getting from the session like this `TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot` in this case the menu fails to appear

```
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT = HMENU
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT {
        special = directory
        special.value = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot
```

...

but this will

```
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT = HMENU
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT {
        special = directory
        special.value = 116
```

...

im absolutely sure the variable is there i can even output in another subpart

```
    SPAN = COA
    SPAN {
        10 = TEXT
        10.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot
        10.wrap = |
    }
```

i have tried setting it as a constant in my template > same result

i make sure it's a integer using (int) when setting the variable in my controller

```
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT = HMENU
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT {
        special = directory
        special.value = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot
        special.value.insertData = 1
```

no effect

```
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT = HMENU
    MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT {
        special = directory
        special.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot
```

no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT = HMENU
MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT {
    special = directory
    special.value.stdWrap.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot
```

Definition of `special.value` in HMENU[1] says that it can be `stdWrap` type which includes `data` parameter.

[1] http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/HMENU

Comment: it's working !! a sub question if may. how can i assign two PID's there

Comment: My first thought - make COA and print 2 HMENUs one after another. Can't find any better solutions yet.

Comment: that was my initial implementation but then i saw you can pass a list or pid's but then you can't pass variables from TSFE for example

Comment: Can you explain what variables you have problem with? I din't understand you.

Comment: i was trying to add two PID's in `special.value.stdWrap.data` but it doesnt work and adding TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot, {$commonRoot} special.value doesnt show the menu with the TSFE value

Comment: @alex: There are several ways to get that extra PID value in. Adding `special.value.stdWrap.wrap = |,{$commonRoot}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`special.value` does not support getText[1] (so it won't resolve any values from TSFE, GP, etc.) unless you set `insertData = 1`. Try this:

```
MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT = HMENU
MENU_PROTECTED_ROOT {
    special = directory
    special.value = {TSFE:fe_user|sesData|usergroup|menuProtectedRoot}
    special.value.insertData = 1
```

[1] http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/getText

Comment: it doesnt seem to have any effect

Comment: try it again with the curly brackets around the TSFE-part

Comment: It won't work - `special.value` can be either list of ids or stdWrap. Nothing else.

Comment: well ok, I thought it's got an implizit stdWrap. I guess `special.value.stdWrap.insertData = 1` should do the trick...

Comment: No it won't. What you wrote is related to `special.value.stdWrap`, not `special.value`. Sorry :)

Comment: Just tried it with TYPO3 4.5, it seems to be working either way ;-)